# Удалил не помню какую переменную среды, не открываются загрузки, документы и т.д

Tags: windows

Вчера установил плагин для Vim и удалил переменную среды. Не помню какую. Сейчас не открываются загрузки, документы и т.д. Также перестали грузиться некоторые сайты (потому что с телефона все хорошо). В чем может быть проблема? Вот все скриншоты с путями https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOk0g.jpg .

Comment: "В чем может быть проблема?" -  Вы удалили какую-то переменную среды. Ваш кэп ;-)

Comment: а некотрые сайты это к чему??

Answer (score 1):

Проблему можно решить, выполнив восстановление системы.

Answer (score 1):

Самое просто решенение проблемы сравниь список своих переменных со стандартным например вот [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B_Windows) есть список. Затем решить вопрос как восстановить эту переменную. (ну а вообще для windows одно простое решение это преустановка (lol))